# Error: Call to a member function get()

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to use this provider class to save new user data to database, but I always get this error

> "FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object"

The problem is `get('security.encoder_factory')` is somehow not working. I'm using this to encode the password. Is there any other way or any fix for this code so i can encode the password without getting an error?

this is my provider class code:

```
namespace xxxx\yyyyBundle\Provider;

use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\OAuthUserProvider;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\Response\UserResponseInterface;'

class Provider extends OAuthUserProvider 
{

//.....
    public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response)
    {
        //.....
        if ( !count($result) ) {

            $user = new User();
            $user->setUsername(xxxxx);
            $encoder = $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($user);
            $user->setPassword($encoder->encodePassword(xxxxx, $user->getSalt()));
            $user->setStatus(xxxxx);
            $user->setFID($facebook_id);

            $em = $this->doctrine->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $id = $em->flush();
        } else {
            $id = $result[0]['id'];
        }

        //set id
        $this->session->set('id', $id);


        //parent:: returned value
        return $this->loadUserByUsername($response->getNickname());
    }
}
```

this exact doctrine code working on the user registration with form.

Comment: maybe container is not set? or Provider/OAuthUserProvider doesn't declare this object as a public member?

Comment: This error means that `$this->container` is not an object. Can you show how you declare it? Can you also post your constructor for that class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using `HWIOAuthBundle`. I don't know this bundle but a cursory glace at its source suggests it's not container aware... Hence your issue: you are trying to call a method on a non-object.

Since you are extending `OAuthUserProvider`, you could set up your `Provider` class as a service itself, inject the container (or better yet just the `security.encoder_factory`).

This is not tested but something like:

```
<?php 

namespace Foo\BarBundle\Provider;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactoryInterface;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\OAuthUserProvider;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\Response\UserResponseInterface;

class BazProvider extends OAuthUserProvider 
{ 
    private $encoder; 

    public function __construct(EncoderFactoryInterface $encoder) 
    { 
        // assign injected object as property
        $this->encoder = $encoder; 
    } 

    public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response) 
    { 
        $user = new User();
        // use injected object
        $encoder = $this->encoder->getEncoder($user);
        // implement
    } 
}
```

In your bundle's `services.yml`

```
services: 
    baz_provider: 
        class: Foo\BarBundle\Provider\BazProvider 
        arguments: 
            - @security.encoder_factory
```

Like any service, you call this in any container aware context (such as a controller) like so:

```
$bazProvider = $this->get('baz_provider');
```

Hope this helps :)

**EDIT**

More reading here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/types.html#constructor-injection

Comment: Thanks its working with :)
I just need to put 

"use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactoryInterface"